# Open-source implementation of structured prediction methods

Tags: open-source, machine-learning, prediction

I'm currently interested in [structured prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_prediction) field. I've looked around the web but haven't found any implementations of this kind of algorithms in any language. Have I not searched enough or is there indeed no open source code for this kind of things?

Comment: Since I don't know the field, I won't post an answer, but, did you look on SourceForge? What about these two https://sourceforge.net/directory/os:linux/?q=structured+prediction

Answer (score 1):

You could try [PyStruct](https://pystruct.github.io/) - while it is at an early stage it does cover only max-margin methods and a perceptron, but other algorithms might follow, and of course you are free to help extend it.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Python so Cross Platform